# Sql queries regarding dates

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

```
select sysdate
from dual;
```

```
SYSDATE
-------
03-May-17
```

```
select sysdate -1 
from dual;
```

```
SYSDATE
-------
02-May-17
==============
```

If the run the below sql query

```
select TO_DATE('01-DEC-15','DD-MON-YYYY') - 1
FROM DUAL;
```

I am getting the answer
30-Nov-15

=====
Can any body help me understand this behaviour?

Comment: It seems pretty self-explanatory. What part is disturbing you?

Comment: Everything is consistent. `-1` gets you one day before the date. Where is the problem ?

Comment: Just be aware that SYSDATE also has a time component (which your front-end program does not show... that is controlled somewhere in the settings). " -1 " subtracts exactly 24 hours; `sysdate - 1` will have the same time-of-day component as `sysdate`. Your `to_date(....)` example also has a time-of-day component (in Oracle there are no "pure" dates, without time component); however, in this case, since you did not indicate a specific time, it defaults to 00:00:00.

Comment: Also be aware that your third example is in the year 0015, not 2015... are you asking why that query works at all when you've given a 2-digit year and a 4-digit format?

Comment: FYI: `trunc(sysdate)` to get the date with the time portion removed.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has [a section on datetime/interval arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Data-Types.htm#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705). A number added to or subtracted from a date is treated as a fraction of a day:

> For example, SYSDATE + 1 is tomorrow. SYSDATE - 7 is one week ago. SYSDATE + (10/1440) is ten minutes from now

As @mathguy pointed out, all dates in Oracle have a time component, and `sysdate` has the current server time. You can see what's happening if you display the full value of the date/time. You can do that explicitly with `to_char()` and a suitable format, but for brevity here I'll alter my session NLS settings:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

select sysdate, sysdate - 1
from dual;

SYSDATE              SYSDATE-1           
-------------------- --------------------
 2017-05-03 16:17:47  2017-05-02 16:17:47
```

Both show the same time, but on different days.

You can [truncate a date](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm) to reduce it's precision; by default `trunc(sysdate)` zeros the time elements so it becomes midnight today rather than the current time.

Your third example is slightly more interesting because you are using mismatching values and format masks; with a 2-digit year and a 4-digit `YYYY` mask the year doesn't end up as you might have expected:

```
select to_date('01-DEC-15','DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('01-DEC-15','DD-MON-YYYY') - 1
from dual;

TO_DATE('01-DEC-15', TO_DATE('01-DEC-15',
-------------------- --------------------
 0015-12-01 00:00:00  0015-11-30 00:00:00
```

That probably isn't what you wanted. The `RRRR` mask is more forgiving, as described in the manual:

```
select to_date('01-DEC-15','DD-MON-RRRR'), to_date('01-DEC-15','DD-MON-RRRR') - 1
from dual;

TO_DATE('01-DEC-15', TO_DATE('01-DEC-15',
-------------------- --------------------
 2015-12-01 00:00:00  2015-11-30 00:00:00
```

but it would be better to provide a full 4-digit year anyway:

```
select to_date('01-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('01-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') - 1
from dual;

TO_DATE('01-DEC-2015 TO_DATE('01-DEC-2015
-------------------- --------------------
 2015-12-01 00:00:00  2015-11-30 00:00:00
```

or even more simply, use a [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062):

```
select date '2015-12-01', date '2015-12-01' - 1
from dual;

DATE'2015-12-01'     DATE'2015-12-01'-1  
-------------------- --------------------
 2015-12-01 00:00:00  2015-11-30 00:00:00
```

This also avoids issues with the date *language*; `'APR'` won't be recognised in sessions where the language - specifically `NLS_DATE_LANGAUGE` - isn't English (unless it's coincidentally a recognised abbreviation ion another language, but some months will still fail). It's better to use month numbers. If you must use names or abbreviations, you can specify the language they are in with the optional third argument to `to_date()`. But literals are still easier if you aren't converting from a string variable.